# Find longest sub-array with no repetitions

Tags: c, arrays, loops

The task is to find the longest contiguous sub-array with all elements distinct.

**Example** **Input** {4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0} **Output** {3, 2, 1, 0}

**Algorithm**

1. Extract first sub Array (here 431)
2. Extract second sub Array (here 31)
3. Compare number of elements and keep the array with the biggest number (keep 431)
4. Return to 2

**Problem** The output is incorrect

```c
/* Free old array and replace it by the new array
 * If we only want to free old array and replace it by a new array
 * Function will free old array and replace it by a new array with size equal to maximum size it can have 
 * Maximum size is the size of the input array
 */
int* newArray(int* oldArray,int* newArray, int sizeArray, int sizeFArray)
{
    if (newArray == NULL) {
        int* temp = malloc(sizeFArray * sizeof(int));
        if (temp == NULL)
            exit(1);

        return temp;    
    } else {
        memcpy(oldArray, newArray, sizeArray);
        return oldArray;
    }
    printf("Error");
    exit(1);
}
//int isAvailable(int* array , int size, int number) checks if number is available in array (return 0 if true, 1 if false)
//printArray(int* array, int size) is a simple function to print an array
void subArray(int* inputArray, int sizeInputArray) 
{
    int* candidate = malloc(sizeInputArray * sizeof(int));
    if (candidate == NULL)
        exit(1);
    int sizeCandidate = 0;
    int* newCandidate = malloc(sizeInputArray * sizeof(int));
    if (newCandidate == NULL)
        exit(1);
    int sizeNewCandidate = 0;

    //We will first fill the candidate
    while (sizeCandidate < sizeInputArray && isAvailable(candidate, sizeCandidate, *(inputArray + sizeCandidate)) != 0) {
        *(candidate + sizeCandidate) = *(inputArray + sizeCandidate);
        sizeCandidate++;    
    }
    int index = 1;
    //Check all potential new candidates
    //If new candidate holds more elements than the current candidate
    //Current candidate will be replaced by new candidate
    //Else we will redo the process and check using the next candidate if availble
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeInputArray; i++) {
        if(isAvailable(newCandidate, sizeNewCandidate, *(inputArray + i)) == 0) { 
            if (sizeNewCandidate > sizeCandidate) {
                candidate = newArray(candidate, newCandidate, sizeNewCandidate, sizeInputArray);
                newCandidate = newArray(newCandidate, NULL, 0, 0);
                sizeCandidate = sizeNewCandidate;
                sizeNewCandidate = 0;
                i = ++index;
            } else {
                newCandidate = newArray(newCandidate, NULL, 0, sizeInputArray);
                sizeNewCandidate = 0;
                i = ++index;
            }
        } else {
            *(newCandidate + sizeNewCandidate) = *(inputArray + i);
            sizeNewCandidate++;
        }
    }
    printArray(candidate, sizeCandidate);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: @klutt for input: {4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 0} output (4, 3, 1}

Comment: You need second `for` loop, for repeating your algorithm. Right now, you only find only one subarray, which is why, output is `{4, 3, 1}`.

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli Not sure why i need a second for loop. I already have a ```while``` loop to get the first sub array and then the ```for``` loop is used to get all potential sub array. The output ```{4, 3, 1}``` is taken in the ```while``` loop

Comment: Your while and for loop runs once per function call

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli the value of ```i``` isn't going from ```1 to sizeInputArray``` in one run..I mean if we find any repetition, the value of ```i``` is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code looks more compact and has clear comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

int check(int a[], int i, int j)
{
    for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
        for (int l = k + 1; l < j; l++)
            if (a[k] == a[l])
                return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int s = 0; // start position of the best candidate
    int m = 1; // length of the best candidate
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(0); // length of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // for every start position
        for (int j = i + m + 1; j <= n; j++) { // for every lengh if it more than the best one
            if (check(a, i, j)) { // check if it contains repetitions
                if (j - i > m) { // if no repetions
                    s = i; // update the candidate
                    m = j - i; // and length
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("{%d", a[s]);
    for(int i = s + 1; i < s + m; ++i)
        printf(", %d", a[i]);
    printf("}\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This works and gives the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the complexity of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
//  int x[] = { 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int x[] = { 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 0 };
    int offset;

    int cur_offset = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int max_offset = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        for (int j = i-1; j >= cur_offset; j--) {
           if (x[i] == x[j]) {
             if (max <= i - j) {
                 max = i - j;
                 max_offset = j + 1;
             } else if (max_offset == cur_offset) {
                 max = i - max_offset;
             }
             cur_offset = j + 1;
             break;
           }
        }
    }
    if (max < sizeof(x) / sizeof(int) - cur_offset) {
        max_offset = cur_offset;
        max = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int) - max_offset;
    }
    printf("%d", x[max_offset]);
    for (int i = max_offset + 1; i < max_offset + max; i++)
        printf(", %d", x[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: For ```x[] = { 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 0 };``` **output** ```1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 0``` which is not exactly what i want

Comment: Yes - I was not updating the start when I updated the end on no miss in the loops.

Comment: @Mohamed can you comment on the complexity of the code.  Is this what was given to you in your course?

Comment: @smac89 the correct output should be ```3, 2, 5, 0```

Comment: @G.AllenMorris||| complexity doesn't matter, it's just a problem i found online and i want to solve it.

Comment: This answer is also correct, marked the other one correct because it's simpler tho..Thanks anyway!